# How can I create a map of methods in Lua?

Tags: lua

I want to create a table that contains the functions of another table, like this:

```
party_animal = {}

function party_animal:dance()
     -- dance
end

function party_animal:dance_furiously()
     -- extreme dance
end

method_map = {
    'idea_one': party_animal:dance,
    'idea_two': party_animal:dance_furiously,
}
```

Then, with this I could invoke one of the functions like this: `method_map[1][2]()`. I can get this working when I use the `.` operator in place of the `:`, but I would like access to `self`.

The error I get is this:

```
stdin:2: '}' expected (to close '{' at line 1) near ':'
```

Comment: method_map[1][2]. method_map[1] is nil hence you cannot index method_map[2]. Even if method_map[1] were a table, method_map[1][2] would be nil and you cannot call nil values either.

Comment: This is due to me using the wrong syntax for the table?

Comment: @MattDeacalionStevens No, this is because you use string keys when you are creating table and try to access values with numbered keys. `table[1]` tries to access keys defined with: `table[1] = foo` or `table = { foo }`. In short if you omit keys in `{}` then all values will be indexed with numbers starting from *1*. `table = { "a", "b", "c" }` will result in `table[1] == "a"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Lua Reference Manual: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.9

> Table constructors are expressions that create tables. Every time a
>   constructor is evaluated, a new table is created. A constructor can be
>   used to create an empty table or to create a table and initialize some
>   of its fields. The general syntax for constructors is

```
tableconstructor ::= ‘{’ [fieldlist] ‘}’
fieldlist ::= field {fieldsep field} [fieldsep]
field ::= ‘[’ exp ‘]’ ‘=’ exp | Name ‘=’ exp | exp
fieldsep ::= ‘,’ | ‘;’
```

> Each field of the form [exp1] = exp2 adds to the new table an entry
>   with key exp1 and value exp2. A field of the form name = exp is
>   equivalent to ["name"] = exp. Finally, fields of the form exp are
>   equivalent to [i] = exp, where i are consecutive integers starting
>   with 1. Fields in the other formats do not affect this counting.

As you see something like

```
method_map = {'idea_one' : party_animal:dance}
```

is not possible because its not valid syntax for table constructors.

Replace : with = and remove the '' to make it a valid expression.

method_map = {idea_one = party_animal:dance} will avoid the error message

> stdin:2: '}' expected (to close '{' at line 1) near ':'

But you will see another error message about missing function arguments.

That's because the colon operator is only valid for function calls and definitions. Not for indexing table elements, which you actually want to do.

`method_map = {idea_one = party_animal.dance}` will not cause any errors.

Of course you cannot access party_animal through self then.

How can we achieve this? Calling `method_map:dance()` will have self refer to method_map.

But if we write

`method_map = {idea_one = function () return party_animal.dance(party_animal) end}`

or the equivalent

`method_map = {idea_one = function () return party_animal:dance() end}`

using the syntactic sugar with the colon operator, 
 we finally get what we want.

Now self will refer to party_animal if we call `method_map:dance()`

Comment: The last example can be changed to `method_map = {idea_one = function () return party_animal:dance() end}`.

Comment: @nobody oh yeah of course. I added the optional syntactic sugar version

Answer (score 4):

```
party_animal = {}

function party_animal:dance()
     -- dance
end

function party_animal:dance_furiously()
     -- extreme dance
end

method_map = {
    idea_one = party_animal.dance,
    idea_two = party_animal.dance_furiously,
}
```

This will work as intended. Why?

First of all, please do notice that your table body has been changed to match lua syntax. The error you got is caused by invalid table definition as pointed out by Piglet in a very detailed manner.

Secondly, this definition of function

```
function table:foo() end
```

is the same as this one

```
function table.foo(self) end
```

Passing function reference does not change its parameters. First parameter still will be `self` and if you call this function using `:` then `method_map` will be passed as `self`.

In case you want to have `party_animal` as `self` in functions from `method_map` you will need to use additional functions:

```
method_map = {
    idea_one = function (...) return party_animal.dance(party_animal, ...) end,
    idea_two = function (...) return party_animal.dance_furiously(party_animal, ...) end,
}
```

[Lua 5.3 Reference Manual on function defining and calling](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.11).

Comment: I think he wants to access party_animal through self. In your example self would refer to method_map. Also using table as a table name is not very nice as it is already used to provide Luas standard table manipulation library.

Comment: @Piglet I understand it differently: he worries that passing function without `:` will make it impossible to access `self`. Well I guess we should wait for him.

Comment: Thank you, these thorough explanations were brilliant! And it was a bit of both, I wanted to pass a table value as a callback but I wanted the function to have access to `self`... I understood the `:` operator did this, but I couldn't get it to work. The very end of @Piglet's answer was spot on!

Comment: And, thank you for pointing out the incorrect syntax. I've been learning Lua for the past few days, and I'm still instinctively writing Python!